# Change column letter instead of row number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have an excel formula but when i drag in order to apply it to all columns it changes the wrong values.

when i drag it it change the row numbers but i need it to change the column letters B to C, D, E etc...

is it possible or do i have to change them manually?

Heres my formula:
Error mark with bold

=SE(E(Tabela2[@[Nº Clínico]]=DESLOCAMENTO('Fichas Clinicas'!B$4;;'Fichas Clinicas'!B$4); DESLOCAMENTO('Fichas Clinicas'!B$157;;**'Fichas Clinicas'!B$157**))="Sim");
T("SIM: "&DESLOCAMENTO('Fichas Clinicas'!B$166;;ROW(B166)));"Nao")

Comment: Got this but it still doesnt change althoug is give the proper result:                                                    =SE.ERRO(SE(E(É.NÚM(--(Tabela2[@[Nº Cli]]=ÍNDICE(Fichas!$B4:$W4; CORRESP(Tabela2[@[Nº Cli]];Fichas!$B4:$W4;0)))); ÍNDICE(Fichas!$B158:$W158; CORRESP(Tabela2[@[Nº Cli]];Fichas!$B4:$W4;0))="Sim"); "Sim: "& ÍNDICE(Fichas!$B167:$W167; CORRESP(Tabela2[@[Nº Cli]];Fichas!$B4:$W4;0));"Nao");"Nao")

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using `OFFSET` and `ROW`. For example, if you have a formula referencing **A1** that you wish to drag down to reference **B1**, **C1**, **D1**,...etc. You could use the following formula

```
=OFFSET(A$1,,ROW(A1)-1)
```

Therefore, try this:

```
=SE(E(Tabela2[@[Nº Clínico]]=OFFSET('Fichas Clinicas'!B$4,,ROW(B4)-1); OFFSET('Fichas Clinicas'!B$157,,ROW(B157)-1)="Sim");T("SIM: "&OFFSET('Fichas Clinicas'!B$166,,ROW(B166)-1));"Nao")
```

Comment: tried but it gives error:     =if(and(Tabela2[@[Nº Clínico]]=offset("'Fichas Clinicas'!B:XXX";5;1); 'Fichas Clinicas'!B157="Sim");T("SIM: "&'Fichas Clinicas'!B166);"Nao")

Comment: It seems that your excel uses `;` instead of `,` in formulas. Try change these.

Comment: I've given your formula a shot in my answer above. Let me know if it works.

Comment: nothing :(  My office is in pt SE=If, E=And and Deslocamento=Offset                                                                                                                              =SE(E(Tabela2[@[Nº Clínico]]=DESLOCAMENTO('Fichas Clinicas'!B$5;;ROW(B5)-1); DESLOCAMENTO('Fichas Clinicas'!B$157;;ROW(B157)-1)="Sim");T("SIM: "&DESLOCAMENTO('Fichas Clinicas'!B$166;;ROW(B166)-1));"Nao")                                                            It dont give error but it gives #NOME?